# Python Cachetools unless

Tags: python, caching

I am learning how to use caching in python for the first time. I'm trying out cachetools and have run into an issue. I got caching to work fine using the below annotation above my method. Does cachetools have an "unless" function? So it will cache **unless** some variable is false after code is executed. Currently it caches every time no matter what. I have searched and am not able to find an answer.

```
@cached(cache=TTLCache(maxSize=64, ttl=300)
Def retrieveValues(input)
    Return 'testValue'
```

But is it possible for something like:

```
@cached(cache=TTLCache(maxSize=64, ttl=300, unless="myValue")
Def retrieveValues(input)
    #don't cache in this situation
    MyValue=False
    return 'testValue'
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: For example, if you call a service to retrieve some values and that service errors or returns bad data. I dont want bad data cached to be returned next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no.  But you can work around it.  If you don't want the answer you got, then throw an exception. This will cause the cache not to save the returned value, since there is no return value.

You will have to have an enclosing function catch the exception, and deal with  it however you want.

Comment: That's the route I'm going now. I figured that this would be a common need when caching